# android ui widget init causing errors

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm VERY new to android programming, so please forgive.

I have an assignment in which I need to add a text box to the xml of the current codebase and then change a variable in the code when the user edits the text box.

So I added the text box, and it's showing up fine, but when I try to initialize it I get an error that the app has stopped unexpectedly and a bunch of stuff in LogCat.

CLARIFICATION: only the last textbox, intersymboltime, causes the errors. If I comment out its initialization everything runs fine.

a sample of my xml (first two are from the existing code, for comparison):

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hostText"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/portlabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/portText"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:hint="@string/portHint"
        android:inputType="number|textNoSuggestions" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/portText"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/symboltime" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/intersymboltime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/symboltimehint"
        android:inputType="number" />
```

in my onCreate (first two calls are in existing code, for comparison):

```
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.hostText)).setText(mServerHost);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.portText)).setText(new Integer(mServerPort).toString()); 
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.intersymboltime)).setText(mClient.portToIntersymbolTime(mServerPort, 1));
```

portToIntersymbolTime returns as expected.

what am I missing?!

EDIT: my logcat logs:

04-13 18:10:17.556: W/ResourceType(716): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000100
04-13 18:10:17.566: D/AndroidRuntime(716): Shutting down VM
04-13 18:10:17.566: W/dalvikvm(716): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.uw.cs.cse461.sp12.timingframing/edu.uw.cs.cse461.sp12.timingframing.TimingFramingAndroidActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x100
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x100
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at edu.uw.cs.cse461.sp12.timingframing.TimingFramingAndroidActivity.onCreate(TimingFramingAndroidActivity.java:39)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-13 18:10:17.576: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  ... 11 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting your logcat would help narrow it down for sure.  The first place I would look is what is the return type of `mClient.portToIntersymbolTime(mServerPort, 1)`.  EditText requires type `CharSequence`.  I am sure you need to use `.toString` or something like that.

Comment: the return type is an int. I assumed it would take anything println or similar would take, meaning an int would be ok. Was that a misconception?

Comment: mClient is an extention of another class you could add a toString method (assuming there isn't one there already) to create and format the string you want.  Or if it is an int then save it to int and use toString as: `new int symbolTime = mClient.portToIntersymbolTime(mServerPort, 1);` then `((TextView)findViewById(R.id.intersymboltime)).setText(symbolTime.toString)`

Comment: Another thought, if this is getting updated regularly, you should save the controls you get from findViewById to variables.  This should speed this up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

With the information given it is really difficult to debug your code. Could you please give us the error logs from Logcat, plus your `portToIntersymbolTime` code?
Based on what I see now, hostText is missing from your xml. But I presume (since you are saying `((TextView)findViewById(R.id.hostText)).setText(mServerHost);` is part of the existing code) that you just haven't pasted that section of your xml.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, it's the last one, intersymboltime, that's causing the error. I just provided snippets so it wasn't a giant chunk of code. I'll try to figure out logcat enough to post the error logs.

Comment: If you are using eclipse, logcat could be added as a dockable window to it. Go to "Window->Show View->Others". Expand Android and pick logcat. Run your code again, the error is displayed in red there.